# copy precedent value 2d dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I want to create a 2d growing dynamic array with use of char. The problem is that my function put all word in the same row. The dynamic allocation is not good but I don't know how to correct this.

```
    void display(char** data, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
            cout << data[i][j];
        cout << endl;
}
void add(char** &data, int length, char* word)
{
    if (length == 1)
    {
        data = new char* [length];
    }

    data[length-1] = new char[strlen(word)+1];
    strcpy_s(*(data + length -1), strlen(word) + 1, word);
    data[length - 1][strlen(word) + 1] = '\0';

}
int main()
{
    char** data = NULL;
    int choice = 0, length = 0; char name[80];
    cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
    while (cin >> choice && choice != 3)
    {
        
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 0:
            cout << "Enter name to add: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();  cin.getline(name, 80);
            length++;
            add(data, length, name);
            break;
        }

        cout << endl << "Enter your next choice: " << endl;
    }
```

This is what is get

```
Enter your choice
    0
    Enter name to add:
    jhon
    jhon
    
    Enter your next choice:
    0
    Enter name to add:
    marc
    jhonmarc
```

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve] for including in a question. No superfluous code but enough that you can take it and compile it without changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that instead of

```
if (length = 1)
```

you meant to write

```
if (length == 1)
```

In C++ `=` means assignment and `==` means equality.

Seems your code has other bugs though. You never grow the size of `data`. Do it the easy way and use `std::vector<std::string>`

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    int choice = 0, length = 0; std::string name;
    cout << "Enter your choice" << endl;
    while (cin >> choice && choice != 3)
    {
        
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 0:
            cout << "Enter name to add: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();  getline(cin, name); // read name
            data.push_back(name); // add name to data
            break;
        }

        cout << endl << "Enter your next choice: " << endl;
    }
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to use simple array like in my example. So If you can help me understand why this not work, it will be graceful

Comment: @codingbest Because then only time you allocate any memory for `data` is when `length` equals 1. But really you need to reallocate data whenever you add a new name. Reallocating also means that you have to copy all the existing names from the old array to the new bigger array.

Comment: Can I copy element without a new array ? Can you explain how ?

Comment: @codingbest No, you need a new array. The array you allocate has room for only one name, so when you add another name you need to allocate a new array.